# upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream docker ubuntu fastcgi

Tags: ubuntu, docker, nginx

upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream:  "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock:"

```
 server {
  ...
  ...
  location ~ '\.php$|^/update.php' {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
    #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:7777;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 180;

  }
}
http {
  proxy_buffering off;
}
```

I am getting this on my local docker. I've tried different values for the buffers and buffers size. Are there any suggestions on how to counter this?

Comment: Can you see what response was sent from your script?

Comment: It is "upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream docker" what nginx logs

Comment: I mean to say can see something your PHP-FPM log?

Comment: no notice in the php-fpm log unfortunately.